# Talend Run If Trigger with context variables

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have a question regarding the output of a job.

Would it be possible to make an output of a job dynamic?
What I mean is being able to configure a wanted output via a property or something? The user should be able to choose in what kind of database he wants the data to be imported by modifying a property.

Apparently, this can be done using a runIf - I unfortunately could not figure out how to do that.

The run if can only be used for booleans. For instance when a condition is met, the existence (or non-existence) of a file, if the number of rows returned is greater than 100, and countless other conditions.

How would it be possible the check if the context variable equals a specific String? For instance, if context.test = "postgres" then tpostgresqloutput, if context.test = "snowflake" then tsnowflakeoutput?

e.g.

```
job > tPostgresqlOutput > run if > context.test = "postgres"
job > tsnowflakeoutput > run if > context.test = "snowflake"
```

Thanks,
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For String comparison in RunIf, you can use:

```
context.test.equalsIgnoreCase("postgres")
```

You may want to connect the appropriate dataflow to the above RunIf depending on whether it is postgres or snowflake.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that leads to a type mismatch - cannot convert from boolean to String

Comment: The condition in RunIf should evaluate to Boolean, that is what the expression does. I assume your context.test variable is String datatype. Where do you get "cannot convert from boolean to String" error?

Comment: Exactly, my context.test is a String datatype.
tMap -> tjavarow -> runif -> db is what I do

Comment: RunIf is used for control flow, not dataflow. You might need to change your flow like this: RunIf -> Source -> tMap -> tJavaRow -> db_postgres. This will be order1 of runIf if context.test is postgres. And in order2, you can do the same for snowflake.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense. I'll try that and will let you know how it went. Thank you!

Comment: I tried it and attached screenshots of my job for a better understanding. I still can't make it work.

Comment: @Djabone -Did you write the condition in the settings of RunIf link? context.test.equalsIgnoreCase("postgres"). The code that you shown - if is blank means there is no condition written in settings of RunIf link.

Comment: Yes of course. That's what is disturbing me ... the tjava contains context.test.equalsIgnoreCase("postgres") >runif > rest of job

Comment: @Djabone - Have you written the condition in tJava or RunIf? You have to write inside RunIf (not tJava).

Comment: Well, that was the problem. I literally did not find any document saying the condition had to be in the IF trigger. Thought it had to be in a msgBox or a java component before the if. Thank you, it's working fine now. I'll mark your answer as correct!

Another thing is that the more databases I have, the bigger my job is since I always have to duplicate it with different outputs per db. Would be really cool if there was a "nicer" way to do it :)